# Arrow pointing downwards in div

Tags: html, css, forms, authentication

I don't know how to put this question but here's what I wanna do. I have made a login form. I want the bottom of my login form to look something like this

[image: login form bottom]

So far I have this:

My css:

```
/*****  Login  *******/
fieldset {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
}

input {
    border: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type="submit"] { cursor: pointer; }

/* ---------- LOGIN-FORM ---------- */

#login-form {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #ea6e10;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#login-form h3 {
    background-color:#ea6e10;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: right;
    }

#login-form fieldset {
    background: #fff;
     border: 1px #ea6e10;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}


#login-form input {
    font-size: 14px;
}

#login-form input[type="username"],
#login-form input[type="password"] {
    background: #dcdcdc;
    padding: 12px 10px;
    width: 238px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#login-form input[type="username"] {

}

#login-form input[type="password"] {
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
}

#login-form input[type="submit"] {
    background: #ea6e10;
text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

#login-form input[type="submit"]:hover { 
  background: #ea6e10; 
}
```

```css
/*****  Login  *******/
fieldset {
 border: none;
 margin: 0;
}

input {
 border: none;
 font-family: inherit;
 font-size: inherit;
 margin: 0;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type="submit"] { cursor: pointer; }

/* ---------- LOGIN-FORM ---------- */

#login-form {
 margin: 10px;
 width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #ea6e10;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#login-form h3 {
 background-color:#ea6e10;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 0;
 padding: 20px;
 text-align: right;
 }

#login-form fieldset {
 background: #fff;
  border: 1px #ea6e10;
 padding: 20px;
 position: relative;
}


#login-form input {
 font-size: 14px;
}

#login-form input[type="username"],
#login-form input[type="password"] {
 background: #dcdcdc;
 padding: 12px 10px;
 width: 238px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#login-form input[type="username"] {

}

#login-form input[type="password"] {
 border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
}

#login-form input[type="submit"] {
 background: #ea6e10;
text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 float: left;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-top: 5px;
 padding: 12px 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

#login-form input[type="submit"]:hover { 
  background: #ea6e10; 
}
```

```html
<div id="login-form" style="float:left;">

        <h3>Login</h3>

        <fieldset>

                <input type="username" required value="username" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='username'" onFocus="if(this.value=='username')this.value='' "> <!-- JS because of IE support; better: placeholder="username" -->

                <input type="password" required value="Password" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Password'" onFocus="if(this.value=='Password')this.value='' "> <!-- JS because of IE support; better: placeholder="Password" -->
 <p><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>
                <input type="submit" value="Login">

              

            </form>

        </fieldset>

    </div>
```

Comment: take a look at http://cssarrowplease.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your CSS like this:

```
/*****  Login  *******/
 fieldset {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
}
input {
    border: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* ---------- LOGIN-FORM ---------- */
 #login-form {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    border: 1px solid #ea6e10;
}
#login-form:after, #login-form:before {
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content:" ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
#login-form:after {
    border-color: rgba(249, 249, 249, 0);
    border-top-color: #f9f9f9;
    border-width: 15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
#login-form:before {
    border-color: rgba(255, 102, 0, 0);
    border-top-color: #ea6e10;
    border-width: 16px;
    margin-left: -16px;
}
#login-form h3 {
    background-color:#ea6e10;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: right;
}
#login-form fieldset {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px #ea6e10;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
#login-form input {
    font-size: 14px;
}
#login-form input[type="username"], #login-form input[type="password"] {
    background: #dcdcdc;
    padding: 12px 10px;
    width: 238px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#login-form input[type="username"] {
}
#login-form input[type="password"] {
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
}
#login-form input[type="submit"] {
    background: #ea6e10;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
#login-form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #ea6e10;
}
```

[**See forked CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hijtp)

Comment: No explanation of what we're doing to actually fix this problem?  It'd be helpful to understand what fixed this for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's your change in an updated CodePen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HyIjC)

And here's what we did:

**CSS**

```
#login-form {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #ea6e10;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}

#login-form:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-50%, -5px);
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: #ea6e10;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

We allow the pseudo-element `after` to be appropriately positioned by setting the `#login-form` to `position:relative`.  The important part of this is the `#login-form:after` part, though.  We're creating a pseudo-element that exists outside the normal document object model to provide the stylistic element.  We take this, define it as a `30px x 30px` box, give it a white background and an orange border, and put it smack dab in the bottom middle of your parent element `#login-form`.  Then, we use transforms to rotate it 45 degrees and scoot it up 5 pixels to meet the bottom border of your parent element.

**This will not work in IE 9 and below**

We need to do some clever things with borders for IE 9 and under.  Here's the change for that scenario:

**CSS**

```
#login-form {
    position: relative;
}
#login-form:before, #login-form:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    content: ' ';
}
#login-form:before {
    border-top: solid 15px white;
    border-left: solid 15px transparent;
    border-right: solid 15px transparent;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
#login-form:after {
    border-top: solid 17px #ea6e10;
    border-left: solid 17px transparent;
    border-right: solid 17px transparent;
    margin-left: -17px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://ilikepixels.co.uk/drop/bubbler/) is a bubble generator:

```
.bubble {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: #ea6e10 solid 2px;
}
.bubble:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 15px 0;
    border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 136px;
}
.bubble:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 16px 16px 0;
    border-color: #ea6e10 transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    bottom: -17px;
    left: 135px;
}
```

And apply this class in your container element. In your case:

```
<div id="login-form" class="bubble" style="float:left;">
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tv8hwj6q/5/)